# Infrared remote PC control stops working after using VLC

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, remote-control

I am using the [hama multimedia pc control](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/hama-fernbedienung-fuer-windows-media-center-1geraete-fernbedienung-208610) to play/pause movies, turn the volume up/down and so on.

It works great with different apps in Windows 10. I use it with Windows Media Player and VLC. However, when I use VLC, close it, and reopen it again, all player specific buttons stop working. Even with the Windows Media Player. Only the volume control works (which is recognized by Windows iteself).

The infrared light bulb still flashes when I press play/pause for example, but nothing happens anymore.

When I restart my PC, everything works as before.

How can I solve this issue such that the player buttons don't stop working with VLC, even when I close/minimize it sometimes?

Comment: Check VLC menu *Tools → Preferences → Hotkeys*, and see if the media keys are anywhere under the Global column.

Comment: @harrymc The media keys are not under the "Global" column, it is completely empty. I used one special media key for fullscreen - and this key works always. Would you suggest to enter the media keys specifically/additionally to VLC? How can I make them appear in the "Global" column (or is that not necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

VLC apparently takes over these keys and destroys their association as used by the
Hama multimedia control.

A possible solution might be to disassociate VLC from your main Windows environment.

This may possibly be done by using
[Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/)
for running VLC isolated inside a virtual sandbox so it can't change any setting
in Windows, only its own settings in its own virtual "Windows".

Comment: Hi, thanks! Is this the easiest way to solve this problem (to use Sandboxie) or is there maybe a workaround by altering VLC?

Comment: Do you know why the Hama keys work initially (after every restart)?

Comment: The keys are correctly associated after restart. I have looked up VLC Preferences/Hotkeys, but I haven't found any way to remap the media keys.

Comment: So, could this somehow be looked at as a VLC bug which I could report?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but it would be safer to float first on their forums the question of why VLC destroys media keys functioning, to get some backing for a bug report.